# Google Analytics keeps saying tracking not installed but

Tags: html, seo, google-analytics

Im having an issue with Google analytics. Originally i had it in the footer and it was showing that tracking was not installed. I just moved it up to the head and the analytics profile is still showing its not installed (confirmed via google's check time) YET within my analytics profile it is tracking? I have 3 visits?

Whats going on here?

www.kildarepainter.com

Comment: Page you provided looks like it is loading GA. 2 potential avenues for investigation: 1. are you using the right web property ID (UA-39945787-1)? 2. The 3rd parameter in the `ga('create' ...)` function is incorrect. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#create

Comment: The tracking code you are using might not be correct, paste it again on head section, preferably not at the start, but just before closing tag. A slight change causes this code not to work.

Answer (score 1):

The GA tracking code on your website doesn't looks like is ok. It should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39945787-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Copy this code and replace it with the one you have on your site. Go to your GA panel and check it out